# azure java SDK interactive login support

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

Does Azure Java SDK support [interactive login](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-connect/)?
I mean like the Azure CLI's "azure login" command.

```
azure login                                                                                                                                                                                         
info:    Executing command login
info:    To sign in, use a web browser to open the page http://aka.ms/devicelogin. Enter the code XXXXXXXXX to authenticate.
```

I was unable to find any reference in the documentation.
Thanks!

Comment: as I know, azure java SDK is used for you to invoke to archive your functions in your java code just like others jar package. the interactive style is often displays in the command line just like win CMD or Linux shell.

Comment: @johnny Thanks, that is correct, but does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently there is no support afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is supported in the latest Azure SDK for Java. You can read more about the functionality [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-user-auth#interactive-browser-credential) and download the libraries from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java)